# How DELETE github repo from drone ci

Tags: github, drone.io

i want to remove github repo from my drone ci v0.3 ( standalone ), but i have a problem with authorizing with github. In 0.3 version you could did with `./drone delete github.com/foo/bar`, but i get such error

> ./drone delete github.com/foo/bar
>   Unauthorized

The problem is that 0.3 version is outdated and documentation is locked http://readme.drone.io/api/authentication/

If you know how configure authentication please help.
PS - board upgrade to the latest version of the right, but impossible now.

Answer (score 2):

For an updated answer, using `1.2.1` I was able to remove repos from my drone list by using the API to delete from the db.

```
curl -X DELETE "https://drone.website.com/api/repos/owner/repo?remove=true" -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with editing db.
Other methods does't work :(

Comment: Answers are meant for full solutions. Could you therefore describe what exactly you had to do to solve your problem? This might help future readers who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The drone command line utility was created for use with drone 0.4 and above. It is therefore not possible to use command line utility with drone 0.3 alpha

Answer (score 0):

We used to have a single drone instance for 2 GitHub organizations and one day we decided to split our drone so that each organization would have its own drone server, so after migration, we had to clean up drone database and I wrote some SQL which could be useful for someone else:

```sql
-- delete templates
delete from templates where template_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete orgsecrets
delete from orgsecrets where secret_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete repo secrets
delete from secrets s using repos r where secret_repo_id = r.repo_id and r.repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete cron
delete from cron c using repos r where cron_repo_id = r.repo_id and r.repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete build cards
delete from cards c using repos r, builds b, stages s, steps st where
    card_id = st.step_id and st.step_stage_id = s.stage_id and s.stage_build_id = b.build_id and b.build_repo_id = r.repo_id and r.repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete build logs
delete from logs l using repos r, builds b, stages s, steps st where
    log_id = st.step_id and st.step_stage_id = s.stage_id and s.stage_build_id = b.build_id and b.build_repo_id = r.repo_id and r.repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete steps
delete from steps st using repos r, builds b, stages s where
    st.step_stage_id = s.stage_id and s.stage_build_id = b.build_id and b.build_repo_id = r.repo_id and r.repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete stages
delete from stages s using repos r, builds b where
    s.stage_build_id = b.build_id and b.build_repo_id = r.repo_id and r.repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete builds
delete from builds b using repos r where
    b.build_repo_id = r.repo_id and r.repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';

-- delete repos
delete from repos where repo_namespace = 'ORG_NAME';
```